# useEffect() cause re-renders and multiple requests to api

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-functional-component, thunk, easy-peasy

## Problem

Functional component causes multiple re-renders causing multiple ajax requests. What is the solution for this?

## This is my code.

```js
export default function MyMenu() {
    let menu = useStoreState(state => state.menu.menu);
    const getMenu = useStoreActions(actions => actions.menu.getMenu);
    let categoryId = useStoreState(state => state);
    const setCategoryId = useStoreActions(actions => actions.menu.setCategoryId);
    const [localCategoryId, setLocalCategoryId] = React.useState(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        getMenu();
    });
    // below is usual return method
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass an array of dependencies as a second argument to `useEffect`. If you want it run only once - pass an empty array, like this:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    getMenu();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks. There is one more thing to it. I want to run it every time the state changes.

Comment: So insert your dependency in array, for example if you want to call it every time `menu` changes - `[menu]`

Answer (score 2):

Missing second argument `[]`, look at it:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    getMenu();
}, []);
```

Comment: Still does not work. The problem is, component re-renders multiple times.